# Can I (easily) use a third-party library to handle serialization for Java RMI?

Tags: java, serialization, rmi, rpc

I very much like the simplicity of calling remote methods via Java's RMI, but the verbosity of its serialization format is a major buzz kill (Yes, I have benchmarked, thanks). It seems that the architects at Sun did the obvious right thing when designing the RPC (speaking loosely) component, but pulled an epic fail when it came to implementing serialization.

Conversely, it seems the architects of Thrift, Avro, Kryo (especially), protocol buffers (not so much), *etc.* generally did the obvious right thing when designing their serialization formats, but either do not provide a RPC mechanism, provide one that is needlessly convoluted (or immature), or else one that is more geared toward data transfer than invoking remote methods (perfectly fine for many purposes, but not what I'm looking for).

So, the obvious question: How can I use RMI's method-invocation loveliness but employ one of the above libraries for the wire protocol? Is this possible without a lot of work? Am I evaluating one of the aforementioned libraries too harshly (*N.B.* I very much dislike code generation, in general; I dislike unnecessary annotations somewhat, and XML configuration quite a bit more; any sort of "beans" make me cringe--I don't need the weight; ideally, I'm looking to just implement an interface for my remote objects, as with RMI).

Comment: I think main challenge with many of libs you mention (but not Kryo) is that they require definition of Schemas, which makes it hard or impossible to do generic use-any-POJO RPC.

Comment: fast-serialization is a JDK serialization compatible reimplementation. Not sure wether there are the necessary hooks to replace the ObjectXXXputStream classes, though. https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time, I did have the same requirement. I had changed rmi methods arguments and return types to byte[].

I had serialized objects with my preferred serializer to byte array, then called my modified rmi methods.

Well, as you mentioned java serialization is too verbose, therefore 5 years ago I did implement a space efficient serialization algorithm. It saves too much space, if you are sending a very complex object graph.. Recently, I have to port this serialization implementation to GWT, because GWT serialization in Dev mode is incredibly slow.

As an example;

rmi method

```
public void saveEmployee(Employee emp){
  //business code
 }
```

you should change it like below ,

```
public void saveEmployee(byte[] empByte) {
        YourPreferredSerializer serialier =   YourPreferredSerializerFactory.creteSerializer();
        Employee emp = (Employee) serializer.deSerialize(empByte);
        //business code
    }
```

EDIT :

You should check [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) . it looks promising.

Comment: That's interesting--can you go into a little more detail?

Comment: possibly reasonable for performance (might be interesting to compare custom to byte[] vs Externalizable here) but then your remote interface becomes a ton of byte[] which could be *anything* at all. This definitely won't be the friendliest interface in the world.

Comment: well, you are right. This is the downside.. :) .. If you have too many domain classes that should be serialized, then externalizable interface is not an option.

Comment: It would be an interesting exercise to compare custom to byte[] vs Externalizable here given that the actual value writing is quite possibly the same cases in each case but the latter has the overhead of Externalizable hence could be seen as the cost of a more descriptive interface. One could then decide if that cost is worth paying.

Comment: This is the best answer, so far. While not technically answering the question (MessagePack is not RMI and is tied to a single wire protocol), it answers the *spirit* of the question (reasonable Java RPC without a bloated wire protocol). If a technically correct answer becomes available, I will accept it; however, there does not appear to be such a library, as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to re-wire RMI, but it might be that specific replacement projects -- I am specifically thinking of [DiRMI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dirmi/) -- might? And/or project owners might be interest in helping with this (Brian, its author, is a very competent s/w engineer from Amazon.com).

Another interesting project is [Protostuff](http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/) -- its author is building a RPC framework too (I think); but even without it supports an impressive range of data formats; and does this very efficiently (as per https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/).

Btw, I personally think biggest mistake most projects have made (like PB, Avro) is not keeping proper separation between RPC and serialization aspects nicely separate.
So ability to do RPC using a pluggable data format or serialization providers seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: +1 "I personally think biggest mistake most projects have made (like PB, Avro) is not keeping proper separation between RPC and serialization aspects nicely separate" -- Stop reading my mind!

Comment: You _can_ somewhat rewire RMI, by implementing the Externalizable interface, though that's a bit intrusive. Possibly rmi-iiop could provide benefit as well

Comment: Well, true, but that is only on per-class basis, not as general rewiring, can't change data format for all objects. But good point still, useful for some situations.

Answer (score 1):

writeReplace() and readResolve() is probably the best combo for doing so. Mighty powerful in the right hands.

Answer (score 1):

Java serialization is only verbose where it describes the classes and fields it's serializing. Overall, the format is as "self describing" as XML. You can can actually override this and replace it with something else. This is what the writeClassDescriptor and readClassDescriptor methods are for. Dirmi overrides these methods, and so it is able to use standard object serialization with less wire overhead.

The way it works is related to how its sessions work. Both endpoints may have different versions of the object, and so simply throwing away the class descriptors won't work. Instead, additional data is exchanged (in the background) so that the serialized descriptor is replaced with a session-specific identifier. Upon seeing the identifier, a lookup table is examined to find the descriptor object. Because the data is exchanged in the background, there's a brief "warm up period" after a session is created and for every time an object type is written for the first time.

Dirmi has no way to replace the wire format at this time.